# Exporting MXML using Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, export

I've been having trouble exporting Adobe Flex using Adobe Air. I can't  find the runnable application Air, and so when I export something to be opened in air it can't be opened. I'm on a Mac Powerbook G4 running OS 10.5.8. Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Export Release Build feature in Flex Builder then it will ask you where you want to create the .air file at.  That .air file is your installer.  You can use an AIR Install badge (see [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour) for an example) to create a web page installer for the Air app.

Comment: the file is not the installer... it says it does not know what program to open it in and air is not available in the list

Comment: The AIR is not installed on the system.  The install badge handles this by auto-installing AIR if needed.

Comment: what badge? is  there a link you can send me? i'm thirteen and havenb't coded anything but a modified example from tour de flex

Comment: Look in the Tour de Flex AIR app under the AIR Capabilities section for the installer badge example.

Comment: I'm sorry im just not understanding it